# Не сдвигается итератор при использовании operator+

Tags: c++, c++11

*Использую g++7*

Основной код:

```
std::vector<int> vec = {5,3,6,14,5};
float arr[] = {5.0, 3.2, 12.1, 12.3, 18.0, 3.0, 12.7};
std::list<float> arrlst(arr, arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(float));

algo::Sort::Bubble(arrlst);
```

Функция algo::Sort::Bubble:

```
template < typename T,
            template <typename, typename...> class Container>
void algo::Sort::Bubble(Container<T>& ctn)
{
    try{

        if(ctn.end() == ctn.begin()) return;

        auto counter = 1;
        while(true){

            auto it = ctn.begin();
            for(; it != ctn.end() - counter; ++it);
                if(*it > *(it+1)) std::swap(*it,*(it+1));

            if(it == ctn.begin()) break;

            ++counter;
        }
    }
    catch(...){
        throw;
    }
}
```

Программа дает сбой в месте (функция Bubble):

```
for(; it != ctn.end() - counter; ++it);
   if(*it > *(it+1)) std::swap(*it,*(it+1));
```

При попытке добавить (сдвинуть итератор) к итератору какое-то число. В чем может быть причина? 
При работе с интовым вектором таких ошибок не возникает.

Вид ошибки:
**
{
"message": "no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘std::_List_iterator’ and ‘int’)"
}
**

Вроде, что-то с типом float и int. Но причем здесь он, это же сдвиг в пространстве адреса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На итераторах от `std::list` операторы `+`/`-` не работают. Их не добавили потому, что они работали бы за линейное время, и с их помощью можно было бы случайно написать неэффективный код.

Зато `++`/`--` работают. Сохраните `ctn.end()` в переменную и каждый раз сдвигайте на одну позицию. `*(it+1)` перепишите через `std::next`.

Comment: next создаст копию итератора. От таких действий эффективность сильно будет страдать?

Comment: @Lee Ну дык и `+`, если бы он работал, тоже создавал бы копию.

Comment: Их не добавили потому, что они работали бы за линейное время, и с их помощью можно было бы случайно написать неэффективный код.
---
В этом есть логика? Если уж можно использовать next, который эквивалентен, то почему не упростить жизнь, добавив эту возможность через перегрузку?

А как понять - 'неэффективный код' в этом случае?

Comment: Получается, у меня никак не получится сделать эффективный код при таком подходе?

Comment: @Lee *"Если уж можно использовать next, который эквивалентен, то почему не упростить жизнь"* Ну, просто так решили. `std::next` работает всегда, а `+` работает только для тех итераторов, для которых его можно написать за константное время. *"как понять - 'неэффективный код' в этом случае"* Если бы `ctn.end() - counter` работал, то он бы каждый раз проходил от последнего элемента списка до элемента с номером `ctn.size()-counter`. Всего было бы около `ctn.size()^2` декрементов итератора. А если сохранить `ctn.end()` в переменную и каждый раз сдвигать на один - то будет `ctn.size()` декрементов.

Comment: То есть это уже вопрос реализации доступа к элементам, не предал этому значение. Не подскажете, что об этом можно почитать? Как правильно загуглить?

Comment: @Lee https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA ?